# On the formal derivative of $X^{p^n} - X$ in an algebraically closed field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

With a prime characteristic $p$.

The formal derivative of $X^{p^n} - X$ is $-1$. Because $F$ is an algebraically closed field and our highest degree is $p^n$, we should have $p^n$ roots all contained in $F$ because $F$ is algebraically closed.

It seems that stating $-1$ is a little redundant with my following, while I'm guessing it isn't. Why do we use the derivative? It is because if the derivative were zero there would be no roots in $F$? I am also wondering why $-1$ implies all roots are distinct.

Comment: A remark on what you wrote: $\frac{d}{dX}\left[X^{p^n}-X\right]=-1$ if and only if $\text{char}\,F=p$, regardless of $F$ being or not algebraically closed.

Comment: Thanks, I need to include that.

Comment: Without looking at the derivative, how would you know that the polynomial has no multiple roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is algebraically closed, that means by definition that $P(X) = X^{p^n} - X$ has a zero in $F$, and by polynomial division, it follows that $P$ has $\deg P = p^n$ zeros **counting multiplicities**.

The fact that $P' = -1$ implies that all these zeros are distinct, for if a polynomial $Q$ has a zero $\alpha$ with multiplicity $m > 1$, then we can write $Q(X) = (X-\alpha)^m\cdot R(X)$ with a polynomial $R$ which satisfies $R(\alpha) \neq 0$, and then we have

$$Q'(X) = m(X-\alpha)^{m-1}\cdot R(X) + (X-\alpha)^m\cdot R'(X) = (X-\alpha)^{m-1}\bigl(mR(X) + (X-\alpha)R'(X)\bigr),$$

so $(X-\alpha)^{m-1}$ is a common divisor of $Q$ and $Q'$. Thus $\gcd(P,P') = 1$ implies that all zeros of $P$ have multiplicity $1$.